# Making summaries using while using tf.keras.Model API

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

How ones make image summaries for tf.keras.Model?

The problem seem trivial at first yet it is currently impossible to solve well.
This seemingly basic feature is currently beyond "user-friendly" tensorflow/keras API.

In tensorflow 1.14 one can make summaries in two ways:

- using `tf.contrib.summary.image`, which doesn't require out of session call of `FileWriter.add_summary(<>)`.
- using `tf.summary.image` which does require it.

Now, the problem with first option is fact that custom file writer object used by `contrib` implementation of `summaries`, requires initialization and `global_step` variable. 
The problem is that I don't know how and when to run init op for it while using framework of `tf.keras.Model`.

In second case problem is that keras graph execution is encapsulated and one can't reuse calculated vales of tensors to feed to file_writer.add_summary()` within keras training/eval loop.

Of course one may think that `tf.keras.callback` would be helpful, yet this is a mistake.
`tf.keras.callback.Callback` does NOT provide the values of computed ops!
Which means you have to execute graph manually with sessions (try that without explicit access to input data). And if you are forced to use sessions: why bother with keras at all?

I challenge you to provide solution for this, that would work for tensorflow 1.13 and 1.14.

Comment: Have you seen the code of the Tensorboard callback? I think it kind of does everything you mentioned: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L1112

Comment: Yes, however it differs for 1.13 and 1.14.
And no, it doesn't do what I want. It does make images of variables (variables are easily accessible through instance of model)

Comment: By variables you mean weights? And what images do you want to make? I guess activations?

Comment: Yes, image of activations.
My current sollutions involves using a property model.train_function.fetches - to add summary ops to list of executed tensors.(i've based it on 1.13 Tensorboard callback code)